# Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error

Tags: android-studio, compiler-errors

Executing tasks: [clean, :app:assembleDebug]

> Configure project :app
>   Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/debug, src/debug/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/debug, src/nullnullDebug]
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
>   Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/release, src/release/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/release, src/nullnullRelease]
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
>
> Task :clean UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:clean
>   Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:preDebugBuild
>   Task :app:compileDebugAidl
>   Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript
>   Task :app:checkDebugManifest
>   Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
>   Task :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug
>   Task :app:generateDebugResValues
>   Task :app:generateDebugResources
>
> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices
>   Parsing json file: D:\ANDROID APP SOURCE CODE\HD WALLPAPERS\codecanyon-7054658-hd-wallpaper-with-material-design\HD Wallpaper Package\Source Code\HDWallpaperNew\app\google-services.json
>   D:\ANDROID APP SOURCE CODE\HD WALLPAPERS\codecanyon-7054658-hd-wallpaper-with-material-design\HD Wallpaper Package\Source Code\HDWallpaperNew\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-sw600dp-v13\values-sw600dp-v13.xml: error: file not found.
>
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
>   Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

  > Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
12 actionable tasks: 10 executed, 2 up-to-date

I did not find Exact issue I already try previous answer of others but non of any solve my issue !

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have `google-services.json` in your android\app folder.